# Want an example of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive integers such that for some natural number k, we have $\frac{a_{n+k}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots +a_{n+k}} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When $a_{n + 1} + \ldots + a_{n + k - 1} > 0$, your expression converges to 0 for small positive $a_{n + k}$. Set $a_1 \ldots a_{k - 1} = 1$ and select successive values inductively so that e.g. $\frac{a_{n + k}}{a_{n + 1} + \ldots + a_{n + k}} = 2^{-n}$.